# something about the MVCObject in google map

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, google-maps

In google map's reference I found the MVCObject,it provide some cool function.

But I am really confused with this object,since I used to do the java web development,so say the MVC I will thought the Model-View-Controller layers.

But in the google map,I can not found anything which can match the three layers.

So I wonder what is the meaning of the MVCObject(how is it differ with the MVC in web development),and what is advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html

Google Maps Javascript API V3 has introduced the implementation of MVC objects that allow map objects to store state and update their presentation automatically

MVC is Model-View-Controller .....